# Cómo puedo ocultar un button y mostrarlo hasta la ultima vista? Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Hola estoy teniendo un problema, quiero que el botón "buttonEnab" aparezca cuando este el ultimo slide (slide4). eh realizado pruebas pero no han funcionado.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!{
        didSet{
            scrollView.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEnab: UIButton!

    var slides:[Slide] = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slides = createSlides()
        setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func createSlides() -> [Slide] {

        let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide1.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "caja_zero")
        slide1.labelTitle.text = "Titulo Tutorial UNO"
        slide1.labelDesc.text = "Descripcion turial uno. realizar paquete"


        let slide2:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide2.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "caja_zero")
        slide2.labelTitle.text = "Titulo Tutorial Dos"
        slide2.labelDesc.text = "Descripcion tutorial dos."

        let slide3:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide3.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "caja_zero")
        slide3.labelTitle.text = "Titulo Tutorial TRES"
        slide3.labelDesc.text = "Descripcion tutorial tres"

        let slide4:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide4.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "caja_zero")
        slide4.labelTitle.text = "Titulo tutorial 4"
        slide4.labelDesc.text = "Descripcion tutorial cuatro"



        return [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4]

    }

// aplicar los slides
   func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex) }

    @IBAction func buttonEnabTapped(slides : [Slide]) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puedes agregar una línea **buttonEnab.isHidden = pageControl.currentPage != 3**  en el método scrollviewDidScroll así cuando el patinador detecte que esta en la pagina 4 (index 3 )  lo va a ocultar y si regresas lo va a mostrar

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

      buttonEnab.isHidden = pageControl.currentPage != 3


}
```